# Python Tunnel to MS SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to access a database in SQL Server, but to access the SQL Server, I have to login and connect to a remote company server.

Many questions suggest SSH tunnelling using `SSHTunnelForwarder(localhost,sshUser,sshPwd,remote_bind_address)` - however I always get an error.

I have several print statements which give the following information:

- Could not receive SSH config file
- 0 Keys loaded from agent
- 0 keys loaded
- Tries to connect to the gateway which is the IP of the server as my user
- Tries to log in with my password
- Fails connection

Comment: Have you tried manually connecting via SSH to make sure the connection has routing and is understood?

Comment: @Alan I am able to login to the server manually through their GUI but when i do it using python I fail.